# After loading a url by open-uri, how to handle the generated Tempfile object?

Tags: ruby, url

I wanna figure out how to download images from internet then store them locally.
Here's what I did:

```
require 'open-uri' # => true

file = open "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/Snip20180323_40.png"
# => #<Tempfile:/var/folders/k0/.../T/open-uri20180524-60756-1r44uix>
```

Then I was confused about this `Tempfile` object. I found I can get the original url by:

```
file.base_uri
# => #<URI::HTTPS https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/Snip20180323_40.png>
```

But I failed in finding a method that can directly get the original file name `Snip20180323_40.png`.

1. Is there a method that can directly get the original file name from a `Tempfile` object?
2. What purpose are `Tempfile` objects mainly used for? Are they different from normal file objects such as: `file_object = File.open('how_old.rb') # => #<File:how_old.rb>`?
3. Can I convert a `Tempfile` object to a `File` object?
4. How can I write this `Tempfile` as the same name file in a local directory, for example `/users/user_name/images/Snip20180323_40.png`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The original filename is only really available in the URL. Just take `uri.path.split("/").last`.
2. Tempfiles are effective Files, with the distinction that when it is garbage collected, the underlying file is deleted.
3. You can copy the underlying file with `FileUtils.copy`, or you can open the Tempfile, read it, and write it into a new File handle of your choosing.
4. Something like this should work:

   ```
   def download_url_to(url, base_path)
     uri = URI(url)
     filename = uri.path.split("/").last
     new_file = File.join(base_path, filename)
     response = uri.open
     open(new_file, "wb") {|fp| fp.puts response.read }
     return new_file
   end
   ```

It's worth noting that if the file is less than 10kb, you'll get a StringIO object rather than a Tempfile object. The above solution handles both cases. This also just accepts whatever the last part of the path parameter is - it's going to be up to you to sanitize it, as well as the contents of the file itself; you don't want to permit clients to download arbitrary files to your system, in most cases. For example, you may want to be extra sure that the filename doesn't include paths like `..\\..\\.."`which may be used to write files to non-intended locations.